# Limit the visibility of records in Solr Search

Tags: java, spring-mvc, solr, lucene

We have a project that we plan to integrate solr search for user records.We want to limit visibility of user records based on their payments.Users has free and premium accounts.If a free account user, his records need to be limit in the search like 10 times a day for a particular recruiter(recruiter is the searcher).
Can be manage this is in Solr?They have a filter option like this?

Help is highly appreciable,

Thanks,

Comment: So you want to limit how often the record of a free user can be found by a certain recruiter, right?

Answer (score 0):

Solr does not provide this type of user-based access control, you will have to do this at the container level, or more likely at the application level. See https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrSecurity for capabilities (most of them environment-dependent, not directly Solr-supported).